# Plotly/Dash leaving unexplained gaps in bar chart when Y contains negative and positive values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, pythonanywhere

I am developing a web app that plots college basketball data scraped from KenPom.com (can be seen at kenpomgraphs.pythonanywhere.com). The first figure is a bar chart using px.bar(), and it is working as intended for the most part. However, when I select conferences that include both positive and negative values for Y, the figure leaves a huge gap between the positive and negative bars.

[image: Bad Gaps]

If I copy the exact same code into a jupyter notebook (replacing `return [fig1]` with `fig1.show()`) I get the desired output.

[image: No Gap]

Here is the code that produces the graph along with the callbacks that provide the arguments. `df` is a dataframe that contains all the data. I filter it down to `dff` based on the arguments provided to the function. I tried adding things like `.reset_index()` and `.copy()` thinking maybe it was a problem with the index or somehow referencing the unfiltered dataframe, but that has not changed the output.

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('fig1', 'figure')],
    [Input('stat-column', 'value'),
    Input('number-teams', 'value'),
    Input('conf', 'value')]
)

def update_figure_1(stat_column_name, number_teams, conf):
    if stat_column_name == 'AdjD' or stat_column_name == 'OppD':
        dff = df.loc[df['Conf'].isin(conf)].sort_values(by=stat_column_name, ascending=True).head(number_teams).reset_index().copy()
    else: dff = df.loc[df['Conf'].isin(conf)].sort_values(by=stat_column_name, ascending=False).head(number_teams).reset_index().copy()

    fig1 = px.bar(data_frame=dff,
                x='Team',
                y=stat_column_name,
                color='Conf',
                color_discrete_map=COLORS
                )
    fig1.update_traces(hovertemplate='%{x}: %{y}')
    fig1.update_traces(marker=dict(line=dict(
                                            width=2,
                                            color='DarkSlateGrey')))
    fig1.update_yaxes(range=[min(dff[stat_column_name]) - abs((min(dff[stat_column_name])*.2)), max(dff[stat_column_name])*1.15])
    if stat_column_name == 'AdjD' or stat_column_name == 'OppD' or stat_column_name == 'Rk':
        fig1.update_layout(xaxis_categoryorder = 'total ascending')
    else: fig1.update_layout(xaxis_categoryorder = 'total descending')
    fig1.update_layout(transition_duration=500)
    fig1.update_yaxes(title=stat_column_name)
    fig1.update_xaxes(title='')
    return [fig1]
```

I am deploying the app using pythonanywhere. When I execute the code in a bash console I can confirm that `dff` only contains the rows I wish to display, so I can't understand why this gap is appearing, and why the same code does not produce the gap when run in a jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why the gap was there, but I was able to fix the problem by removing these lines of code:

```
    if stat_column_name == 'AdjD' or stat_column_name == 'OppD' or stat_column_name == 'Rk':
        fig1.update_layout(xaxis_categoryorder = 'total ascending')
    else: fig1.update_layout(xaxis_categoryorder = 'total descending')
```

and instead adding the argument

```
category_orders={'Team': list(dff['Team'])}
```

to `px.bar()`